# Remove background noise from audio files automatically on Mac

Tags: audio, macos

I am looking to remove background noise from a large number of audio files on Mac. I don't want to use Audacity, as it seems to require a lot of manual work. [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) seemed like a good choice, but unfortunately it only allows you to apply these effect live. I want to remove background white noise from just the audio files themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 free packages that claim to do what you want. One is [WavePad](https://www.nch.com.au/wavepad/index.html?kw=mac%20audio%20editing%20software&gclid=Cj0KCQiAk-7jBRD9ARIsAEy8mh43jRwRzUzvZY4LFDAnGJ-LTSPwDyU9VemD0ZOzlEHKgUUQjB5HuNQaAmYuEALw_wcB) by NCH software and the other is GarageBand by Apple.

The review for Waverpad starts with the following statement. "As my mom used to say, easy peasy pumpkin pie. That’s pretty much WavePad in a nutshell."  That sure sounds inviting and since its free it should be worth a try.

I've never used Garageband but it is also free and come installed on your mac. If not, you can download it from the MacApp Store.

Comment: I just wanted to say, I downloaded Wavepad and I'm an instant fan. It does everything that I need it to do and does it well. It is jam-packed with great features to explore which I might need in the future. It is exactly what I was asking for. Thank you for the superb suggestion!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I'm very glad it helped you.